# How To Block Bad Bots in Amazon S3 (Amazon Simple Storage Service)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have signed up to Amazon Web Services and created a static website via Amazon S3 service ( created a Bucket and mapped a domain to that Bucket).

This service looks great but I have one problem - I don't know how to block Bad Bots and to prevent them to waste my bandwidth ( you all know that Amazon charge for bandwidth)

Amazon Web Services doesn't support .htaccess and I have no idea how to block them.

What I need is to block the bad bots via 2 ways:

1. Via Bot Name, e.g.: BadBot1
2. Via Bot IP, e.g.: 185.11.240.175

Can you please help me to do it?

Comment: check this [How to Configure Rate-Based Blacklisting with AWS WAF and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-configure-rate-based-blacklisting-with-aws-waf-and-aws-lambda/)

Comment: Have not done this but take a look at S3 bucket policies with a Condition that includes NotIpAddress: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3. No idea how "bot name" is indicated or detected.

Answer (score 2):

Your S3 bucket policy will definitely allow you to block specified IP addresses, but there is a size limitation (~20 kb) on bucket policy sizes, which would probably make trying to maintain a policy restricting disreputable IP addresses unfeasible.

AWS's `WAF & Shield` service, fronted by Cloudfront, is the most powerful way AWS provides to block IPs, and you could easily integrate this with an S3 origin. Cloudfront allows you to plug in a `Waf & Shield` ACL, which is comprised of rules that allow or disallow sets of IPs that you define.

AWS has some sample Lambda functions [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-sample) that you can use as a starting point. You would probably want a Lambda function to run on a schedule, obtain the list of IPs that you want to block, parse that list, and add new IPs found to your WAF's IP sets (or remove ones no longer on the list). The `waf-tor-blocking` and `waf-reputation-lists` functions in the above link provide good examples for how to do this.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by detecting Bot Name, but the standard `Waf & Shield` approach is currently to parse Cloudfront logs sent to an s3 bucket. Your s3 bucket would trigger SNS or a Lambda function directly whenever it receives a new gzipped log file. The Lambda function will then download that file, parse it for malicious requests, and block the associated IP addresses. The `waf-block-bad-behaving` and `waf-reactive-blacklist` functions in the repo I linked to provide examples for how you would approach this. Occasionally you will see signatures for bad bots in the user-agent string of the request. The Cloudfront logs will show the user-agent string, so you could potentially parse that and block associated IPs accordingly.